# group rows according to a column in a pandas df (fill with only boolean values)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm struggling with an issue on my pandas DataFrame. i guess I should use the `groupby` method but I can't figure it out properly.

my data looks like this (but with ~200 rows and 5000 columns) :

```
            K00001  K00002  K00003  K00004  K00005  K00009  K00011  K00013   OTU
Root100     True    False   False   True    False   False   True    False    OTU1
Root102     True    False   False   True    False   False   True    False    OTU1
Root105     True    True    False   True    False   False   True    False    OTU1
Root107     True    False   False   True    False   False   True    False    OTU2
Root11      True    False   False   True    True    False   True    False    OTU2
```

i'd like to group the rows according to the last column column 'OTU' in order to have :

```
        K00001  K00002  K00003  K00004  K00005  K00009  K00011  K00013   
OTU1    True    True    False   True    False   False   True    False    
OTU2    True    False   False   True    True    False   True    False
```

The boolean values of each cell being the result of `or` boolean comparisons of each grouped cells (for instance, for `K00002` in `OTU1`, it would be `False or False or True = True`

Can someone give me a hint ?

Thanks.

Comment: what about your index, `Root`. how does that play into the question? also for `otu1` column `k00002` you have True and False. what is the need for that scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df = df.groupby('OTU').any()
print (df)
      K00001  K00002  K00003  K00004  K00005  K00009  K00011  K00013
OTU                                                                 
OTU1    True    True   False    True   False   False    True   False
OTU2    True   False   False    True    True   False    True   False
```

Comment: Didn't thought it was so simple ._.. Thank you !